# Tornado API example with Momoko and RealDictCursor

Tags: python, tornado

I'm learning Tornado and Momoko for an upcoming project and I made a simple API with a `GET user/{id}` endpoint that queries a database in order to search a *User* from a database I created before for another project.

Here's the code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen as gen
import momoko
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
from json import dumps
from datetime import date, datetime

def json_serial(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        return obj.isoformat()
    raise TypeError ("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))

class UserHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return self.application.db
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, user_id):
        cursor = yield self.db.execute("SELECT u.username as username, u.\"isActive\", u.created as created FROM \"User\" u WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1", (user_id,), cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        self.write(dumps(result, default=json_serial))
        self.finish()

def get_app():
    app = tornado.web.Application([
            (r'/user/([1-9][0-9]*)', UserHandler)
        ])
    app.db = momoko.Pool(
            dsn="dbname=test user=test password=test host=localhost port=5432"
            )
    app.db.connect()
    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = get_app()
    app.listen(3000)
    print("Starting loop")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

What do you think about it? Is there a better way to initialize a `Pool` object?

Thanks for any feedback